# How to define a function that creates an asynchronous computation in F#

Tags: .net, f#

How to defined a function that 'mandelbrotAsync m n s e cs' creates an asynchronous computation
which computes an array of booleans with the same size as cs. An
element in this array is true precisely when the complex number at
the corresponding position in cs belongs to the Mandelbrot set
(according to n iterations).

Use the 'divide' function to divide the work into m chunks (ranges)
and then evaluate those in parallel using the Async mechanism.

Whenever this function starts computing on a chunk of input (s, e),
the function must apply the function 'start' to 's'. When it has
completed working on the chunk, then it must apply 'finish' to 'e'.

```
 mandelbrotAsync  :  int
                  -> int
          -> (int -> unit)
          -> (int -> unit)
          -> Complex []
          -> Async<bool []>
```

so that given

```
  m      : int
  n      : int
  start  : int -> unit
  finish : int -> unit
  cs     : Complex []
```

```
type Complex = double * double
```

```
let mandelbrotAsync m n start finish cs = failwith "not implemented"
```

Comment: What do you have so far? Keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a free homework service. You have to show your own attempt first, then we can help you fix problems that you have encountered.